# After swapping in SSD I can’t get into the BIOS on my Lenovo G560

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, bios

I've replaced the hard drive of a Lenovo G560 after the drive died with an SSD. Now it won't let me boot from anything, not to mention it won't let me get into BIOS. From all I found on Google they suggested hitting <kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F12</kbd>/<kbd>Delete</kbd> (even tried the <kbd>FN</kbd> keys with <kbd>FN</kbd>) nothing happens it goes into PXE, exits it and says no device.

I am clueless as to what to do with this laptop, it won't boot to anything, although placing he dead hard disk drive back in showed that it can't "talk" to it and gave an error.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with a lot of Lenovo ThinkPad T540p, T440s, T550 and T450s and sometimes, when pressing the usual <kbd>F12</kbd> key doesn't work, I need to press on <kbd>Enter</kbd> to "interrupt" the boot process and get taken to the startup options (enter Setup, choose boot device, etc). See if that works for you. I know that <kbd>Enter</kbd> is the key to press if Secure Boot and UEFI isn't enabled on these Lenovo laptops.

Comment: Nope, just tried it, nothing.

Comment: Can you remove any USB devices (USB Flash Drive, keyboard, mouse, etc), SD card, CD/DVD, etc. that are inserted in the laptop and try all the keys again? It was another issue I came across from time to time with these laptops.

Comment: No USB devices are connected except the built in keyboard/touch-pad mouse. Regarding DVD, tried that.

Comment: Now, have you tried with an external keyboard (USB), if you have one that you can use?

Comment: I've tried that, nothing. From what I gathered there's a chance the damn BIOS got bricked meaning requires a re-flash and on laptops it ain't easy to do.

Comment: It's possible sadly. Have you tried power cycling your laptop (remove the battery, hold the Power button for 30 seconds, then plug in the AC adapter and power it up) and see if it works after? Worth a try.

Comment: 1. Try ESC also. 2.Whatever key you're trying make sure to press and spam it IMMEDIATLY after powering on.

Comment: Some Lenovo models have a special key that must be pressed and kept BEFORE powering on. Please read YOUR manual which contains specific instructions for YOUR model.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/can-t-access-Bios-on-G560-anymore/td-p/445721) claims it's related to a bad boot HDD:

> problem fixed by taking out the hard drive and putting it into another
> laptop and do the Win 7 startup repair. This fixed the boot issue and
> it booted back into Win7. It was a hibernation issue gone bad. So I
> disable hibernation alltogether with a tweak.  Once I shut the laptop
> off and now I'm able to get into the bios again.

I fixed it by cloning the HDD to another SSD using Macrium Reflect. As soon as I booted the laptop, the POST screen looked a bit different and I was able to enter BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

For people still looking for the answer. The following link helped
https://support.lenovo.com/mx/en/solutions/ht500222#2

Apparently you have to disable fast boot mode in windows. Luckily i had the earlier HD with windows intact when i changed the setting i could access the bios again.

There maybe another way to disable it without windows, but im not sure how yet.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i found , its connecting a HDD with Windows 7 , boot it and when its all loaded , restart and load the bios with F2.

Then you swap the disk with a SSD and the BIOS will work normal again!

PD:sry my english , im from argentina, just trying to help , gl !